# QTimer не работает

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtimer, qprogressbar

[image: Фото]

Зашёл в инструкцию, сделал так же, как там написано, но какая-то ошибка.

Я не уверен, но мне кажется он только для *PySide2* или нет?

Comment: пожалуйста предоставляйте код  и ошибку обычным текстом и не забывайте про минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Прям-таки тоже самое сделали? Уверены? А о чем ошибка тогда?  В сообщении об ошибке точно указано, что вы сделали не так по сравнению с документацией. QTimer прекрасно работает, надо просто быть немного более внимательным

Comment: Аргументом Функции `connect` должна быть другая функция (слот). А вы передаёте объект `QProgressBar`.

Comment: @S.Nick Спасибо, но я вчера уже разобрался. Правда я вот читаю документацию и там не сказано, что передаваться должна функция. Или же я просто не вижу

Comment: [To use it, create a QTimer , connect its timeout() signal to the appropriate slots, and call start() . From then on, it will emit the timeout() signal at constant intervals.](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QTimer.html#detailed-description). Вот собственно здесь и сказано. Да и вообще функция `connect` изначально предназначена для соединения сигналов со слотами. Изучите эту тему перед тем, как идти дальше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не предоставляете минимально-воспроизводимый пример
и это не хорошо.

1. `QTimer` работает.
2. Я предполагаю, что вы хотите сделать муляж прогресс бара.
3. Если утверждение п.2 верно, то вам лучше подойдет `QTimeLine`,
   если нет - предоставьте минимально-воспроизводимый пример,
   который демонстрирует проблему.

> Класс **QTimeLine** предоставляет временную шкалу для управления анимацией.
>
> Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimeline.html

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

        
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.progressBar = QProgressBar()
        self.progressBar.setRange(0, 100)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.progressBar)

        self.timeLine = QTimeLine(1000*10)
        self.timeLine.setFrameRange(0, 100)
        self.timeLine.frameChanged.connect(self.progressBar.setValue)
        self.timeLine.start()
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]